# regex for blank string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

I have a string as:

```
s=

"(2021-06-29T10:53:42.647Z) [Denis]: hi
(2021-06-29T10:54:53.693Z) [Nicholas]: TA FOR SHOWING
(2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]: how are you bane 
(2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]: 
(2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]: #END_REMOTE#
(2021-06-30T08:07:42.029Z) [Denis]: VAL 01JUL2021
(2021-06-30T08:07:42.029Z) [Denis]: ##ENDED AT 08:07 GMT##"
```

I want to extract the text from it. Expected output as:

```
comments=['hi','TA FOR SHOWING','how are you bane',' ','#END_REMOTE#','VAL 01JUL2021','##ENDED AT 08:07 GMT##']
```

What I have tried is:

```
comments=re.findall(r']:\s+(.*?)\n',s)
```

regex works well but I'm not able to get the blank text as `''`

Comment: You have to exclude matching the `]` like `]:\s+([^]\n]*)$`

Comment: Could you please provide the code you use to process your text? The string literal your provided [does not compile](https://ideone.com/9Xofld).

Comment: @Thefourthbird I did...will surely do for rest ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
comments = re.findall(r']:\s(.*?)\n',s)
```

If the space after `:` is always one space, `\s+` should be `\s`. `\s+` means one or more spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude matching the `]` instead in the capture group, and if you also want to match the value on the last line, you can assert the end of the string `$` instead of matching a mandatory newline with `\n`

**Note** that `\s` can match a newline and also the negated character class `[^]]*` can match a newline

```
]:\s+([^]]*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MIcpqn/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9gZ5jH)

```
import re

regex = r"]:\s+([^]]*)$"

s = ("(2021-06-29T10:53:42.647Z) [Denis]: hi\n"
    "(2021-06-29T10:54:53.693Z) [Nicholas]: TA FOR SHOWING\n"
    "(2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]: how are you bane \n"
    "(2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]: \n"
    "(2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]: #END_REMOTE#\n"
    "(2021-06-30T08:07:42.029Z) [Denis]: VAL 01JUL2021\n"
    "(2021-06-30T08:07:42.029Z) [Denis]: ##ENDED AT 08:07 GMT##")

print(re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['hi', 'TA FOR SHOWING', 'how are you bane ', '', '#END_REMOTE#', 'VAL 01JUL2021', '##ENDED AT 08:07 GMT##']
```

If you don't want to cross lines:

```
]:[^\S\n]+([^]\n]*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tvou6G/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could identify all after the colon into an array from capture group 1.

```
re.findall(r'(?m):[ \t]+(.*?)[ \t]*$',s)
```

then loop the array assigning a space to all empty elements.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s= """
... (2021-06-29T10:53:42.647Z) [Denis]: hi
... (2021-06-29T10:54:53.693Z) [Nicholas]: TA FOR SHOWING
... (2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]: how are you bane
... (2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]:
... (2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]: #END_REMOTE#
... (2021-06-30T08:07:42.029Z) [Denis]: VAL 01JUL2021
... (2021-06-30T08:07:42.029Z) [Denis]: ##ENDED AT 08:07 GMT##
... """
>>>
>>> talk = [re.sub('^$', ' ', w) for w in re.findall(r'(?m):[ \t]+(.*?)[ \t]*$',s)]
>>> print(talk)
['hi', 'TA FOR SHOWING', 'how are you bane', ' ', '#END_REMOTE#', 'VAL 01JUL2021', '##ENDED AT 08:07 GMT##']
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples please try following regex.

```
^\(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d{3}Z\)\s+\[[^]]*\]:\s+([^)]*)$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/yL61om/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^\(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}  ##Matching from starting of line ( followed by 4 digits-2 digits- 2 digits here.
T(?:\d{2}:){2}        ##Matching T followed by a non-capturing group which is matching 2 digits followed by colon 2 times.
\d{2}\.\d{3}Z\)\s+    ##Matching 2 digits followed by dot followed by 3 digits Z and ) followed by space(s).
\[[^]]*\]:\s+         ##Matching literal [ till first occurrence of ] followed by ] colon and space(s).
([^)]*)$              ##Creating 1st capturing group which has everything till next occurrence of `)`.
```

***With Python3x:***

```
import re
regex = r"^\(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d{3}Z\)\s+\[[^]]*\]:\s+([^)]*)$"
varVal = ("(2021-06-29T10:53:42.647Z) [Denis]: hi\n"
    "(2021-06-29T10:54:53.693Z) [Nicholas]: TA FOR SHOWING\n"
    "(2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]: how are you bane \n"
    "(2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]: \n"
    "(2021-06-29T11:58:29.053Z) [Nicholas]: #END_REMOTE#\n"
    "(2021-06-30T08:07:42.029Z) [Denis]: VAL 01JUL2021\n"
    "(2021-06-30T08:07:42.029Z) [Denis]: ##ENDED AT 08:07 GMT##")

print(re.findall(regex, varVal, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output will be as follows with samples shown by OP:

```
['hi', 'TA FOR SHOWING', 'how are you bane ', '', '#END_REMOTE#', 'VAL 01JUL2021', '##ENDED AT 08:07 GMT##']
```